# Reduce the rate of my script (it receives information each 1/30 seconds)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm receiving a distance information (in the three axis: x, y, z) between my camera and a target point each 1/30 seconds (i.e, with a frequency of 30 Hz), but my script is running much faster (like at 1E-5 seconds for each decision). I need to slow down the code, so each time I receive 1 distance measurement it makes only one movement.

My code is as follows (I only pasted the part that is interesting):

```
class gonnaGetDown():


def __init__(self):

    self.velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    print "b"

    rospy.Subscriber('/ar_pose_marker', AlvarMarkers, self.detect_marker)

def detect_marker(self, msg):
    print "c"

    saturacion = 0.2

    vel_msg = Twist()   

    if not msg.markers:
        return
    else:

        marker = msg.markers[0]
        print "d"

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "time [us]: ", now.microsecond


if __name__ == '__main__':

rospy.init_node('go_to', anonymous=True)

try:
    rate = rospy.Rate(0.1) #I don't know why this is here, I don't use it
    gonna_get_down = gonnaGetDown()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        print "a"

        rate.sleep()

except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    rospy.loginfo("Node terminated.")
```

So my code prints, for example:

```
b 
b 
a 
c 
d 
time [us]: 607766 
c 
d 
time [us]: 642230
c 
d 
time [us]: 710855 
c 
d 
time [us]: 777346 
c 
d 
time [us]: 807427
c
d 
time [us]: 883408
c
d
time [us]: 916693
c
d
time [us]: 973941 
c 
d 
time [us]: 7659 
c 
d 
time [us]: 80693
```

That's not 30 Hz. I would expect time differences of 33333.3333 nanoseconds. What is happening?